# First-person shooter on Android – how to process mouse events?

Tags: android, event-handling, mouseevent, pointerlock

As a hobby and to learn, whether this is possible, I'm trying to implement a simple first-person shooter for Android. Unfortunately, I ran into a dead end when dealing with mouse event processing.

I already have an `onGenericMotion()`-Listener, which processes `MotionEvent` objects generated by the system framework. The problem is, that `MotionEvent` objects, generated by a mouse merely contain *absolute* coordinates, which tend to get "stuck", once the cursor reaches an edge or a corner of the screen. So I'm thinking relative mouse coordinates. While I found no feature on `MotionEvent` that could deliver relative movements, using

`adb shell su -- getevent -lt /dev/input/event3`

and examining its output revealed that the kernel generates distinct relative motion events when one tries to move the cursor, even when it is stuck in a corner of the screen. So, given that my shooter has su access, I could obtain relative movements.

And now the question: A little bit of Google-fu revealed, that in many first-person shooters, the typical mouse movement is achieved by

1. using relative mouse coordinates and
2. by *re-positioning* the mouse cursor in the center of the screen.

So, the question really is two-folded:

1. Is it possible to re-position the mouse cursor in the center of the screen on Android? and
2. If not, can the typical "first-person-shooter" mouse movement be realised by using relative mouse movement information alone?

Comment: Yes :) Using a mini pc [like this one](http://www.amazon.de/MK-Android-Rockchip-RK3188-Cortex/dp/B00BGC9DT0/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1394216664&sr=8-1&keywords=android+mini+pc). A little odd, I know ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible without root permissions, with the [pointer capture API](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement#pointer-capture) in Android 8.0+ (released August 2017). In summary:

> To request pointer capture, call the [requestPointerCapture()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#requestPointerCapture()) method on the view.
>
> Once the request to capture the pointer is successful, Android calls [onPointerCaptureChange(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onPointerCaptureChange(boolean)), and starts delivering the mouse events.
>
> Your focused view can handle the events by performing one of the following tasks:
>
> 1. If you're using a custom view, override [onCapturedPointerEvent(MotionEvent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onCapturedPointerEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)).
> 2. Otherwise, register an [OnCapturedPointerListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnCapturedPointerListener).
>
> The view in your app can release the pointer capture by calling [releasePointerCapture()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#releasePointerCapture()).

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that [this](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2013/01/programmatically-injecting-events-on-android-part-2/#.UyBSeqGDj2i) completely answers my question. Never mind then.